# Найти хэш-таблицу в HashMap

Tags: java, коллекции, java-hashmap

Начав исследовать такое явление как hash-таблица, я понял, что это некий массив, каждая ячейка которого хранит список, который параметризован двумя типами: *ключ* и *значение*.

Когда я залез в исходники `HashMap`, то увидел следующее:

```
transient Node<K,V>[] table;
```

Если я все правильно понял, и это и есть хеш-таблица, то почему тогда это одномерный массив? Или я что-то не то нашел, и это не она?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Представленный Вами массив является основой для хранения хэш-таблицы.

Но кроме этого, каждый элемент такого массива (*bucket*) содержит ссылку на первый элемент *linked list* (JDK 7 и ранее), либо ссылку на первый элемент *linked list*/ссылку на корневой узел *balanced tree* (JDK 8).

В *linked list*, либо в *balanced tree* находятся пары, которые попали в одну и ту же корзину.

Пример для связного списка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом и хранится эта хэш-таблица.

Comment: А я понял он двумерный просто второй уровень как  linked да?

Comment: @Павел, Строго говоря, нельзя назвать эту структуру двумерным массивом, но да, Вы правильно поняли. Каждый элемент данного массива может являться либо связным списком, либо деревом.

Comment: ну я деревья еще не проходил это у меня следующая тема. Ок большое спасибо что объяснили.

Answer (score 2):

Если бы вы посмотрели, что это за класс, то увидели бы, что это он реализует помимо всего прочего еще и односвязный список

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
    final int hash;
    final K key;
    V value;
    Node<K,V> next; // simple, isn't it?
```

Также есть TreeNode, который является наследником Node, чтобы в сложных случаях можно было реализовать хранение одной корзины не списком, а деревом.

Answer (score 2):

Вы путаете интерфейс и реализацию. HashMap - это таблица, где каждому ключу соответсвует одно значение. То что вы нашли это не сама HashMap, а лишь специальная структура для хранения данных.

Comment: интерфейс - это Map

Comment: а ну да так я про хеш-таблицу для HashMap, а про интерфейс не понял извините((

Comment: @Павел как верно заметили выше, интерфейс у HashMap - это Map. А вы смотрите на детали реализации. Реализация может быть какой угодно.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman да просто у меня следующее задание это создать свою структура данных с хэш-таблицей, а это тема для меня совсем новая. И я как раз выясняю какие бывают идеи для реализации хэш-таблиц. А к стати что разве интерфейс Map что-то знает о хеш-таблице?

Comment: @Павел Map ничего не знает о хэш-таблице. Я думаю, что вам стоит взять более просту реализацию хэш-таблицы.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman а какая простая не подскажите? В смысле где ее искать?

Comment: @Павел в ответ post_zeew нарисована схема. Вот ее и сделайте.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman выше заметили, что интерфейс к вопросу не имеет никакого отношения, вопрос именно про реализацию